# Using variables across Flask routes

Tags: python, flask, routes, jinja2

I am learning Flask and have a question regarding use of variables in the context of routes.For Example, my app.py:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/index")
def index():

   a=3
   b=4
   c=a+b

return render_template('index.html',c=c)

@app.route("/dif")
def dif():

   d=c+a

   return render_template('dif.html',d=d)


if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run()
```

Under the route /dif the variable d is calculated by taking the values of already calculated c and a.How to share variables c and a between pages, so that variable d is calculated and rendered to dif.html?

Thank You

Answer (score 16):

<strike>If you do not want to use [Sessions](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#sessions) one way to store data across routes is</strike> (**See the update below**):

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

class DataStore():
    a = None
    c = None

data = DataStore()

@app.route("/index")
def index():
    a=3
    b=4
    c=a+b
    data.a=a
    data.c=c
    return render_template("index.html",c=c)

@app.route("/dif")
def dif():
    d=data.c+data.a
    return render_template("dif.html",d=d)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

N.B.: It requires to visit `/index` before visiting `/dif`.

---

#### Update

Based on the davidism's comment the above code is not production friendly because it is not thread safe. I have tested the code with `processes=10` and got the following error in `/dif`:

[image: internal server error for processes=10]
The error shows that value of `data.a` and `data.c` remains `None` when `processes=10`.

---

So, it proves that **we should not use global variables in web applications**.

We may use [Sessions](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#sessions) or Database instead of global variables.

In this simple scenario we can use sessions to achieve our desired outcome.
Updated code using sessions:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, session
app = Flask(__name__)
# secret key is needed for session
app.secret_key = 'dljsaklqk24e21cjn!Ew@@dsa5'
@app.route("/index")
def index():
    a=3
    b=4
    c=a+b
    session["a"]=a
    session["c"]=c
    return render_template("home.html",c=c)

@app.route("/dif")
def dif():
    d=session.get("a",None)+session.get("c",None)
    return render_template("second.html",d=d)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(processes=10,debug=True)
```

Output:

[image: index]
[image: dif]

Comment: If I install a package via pip install xyz. Then, import xyz in route.py. Then, in the route fucntion if I assign or mutate a variable in xyz, via xyz.varname.append or xyz.varname=100. Now, this will affect varname in all other user threads?

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables in flask using by writing the variable passed from HTML like this in your URL. 
,

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route("/index")
    def index():

       a=3
       b=4
       c=a+b

    return render_template('index.html',c=c)

    @app.route("<variable1>/dif/<variable2>")
    def dif(variable1,variable2):

       d=c+a

       return render_template('dif.html',d=d)


    if __name__ == "__main__":
```

Your html will be like:
as form:

```
<form action="/{{ variable1 }}/index/{{ variable2}}" accept-charset="utf-8" class="simform" method="POST"
```

As href:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('index',variable1="variable1",variable2="variable2") }}"><span></span> link</a></li>
```