# Import a global variable from an external function into flask app

Tags: python, flask

I am really new to flask and fairly new to python.

Here is my issue:
I have created a flask app that displays a bunch of matplotlib charts with the following structure:

```
└──app
   ├──templates
   |  └──index.html
   ├──assets
   ├──functions
   |  └──by_continent.py
   └──app.py
```

So the app gets the country selected by the user in the index.html (countryVal), passes it to my matplotlib chart by_country.py and plots the in-memory image generated in the html file. Works perfect.

My app.py looks like:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request    
from functions.by_continent import scatter_plot


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():

    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])

def getCountry():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        scatter_img = scatter_plot(countryVal)
        return render_template('index.html', 
                               scatter_img= scatter_img,  
                               country=countryVal)
    else:
        return render_template('index.html')
```

and my by_continent.py script where the matplotlib chart and the variable countryCode is generated and it looks like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def scatter_plot(countryVal):
    
   global countryCode

   ......

   pop = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * from population", conn)

   df = df.filter(['Edition','Country/Territory','Region', 'Total', 'status_name'])

   countryCode = pop[pop.country_name.str.lower() == current_country.lower()]['country_iso_2code'].values[0]

    .....

    return scatter_img
```

There is a variable on by_country.py that I want to pass to the html.code, so I defined it as a global variable and I am passing it to the app as **country_code= scatter_plot.countryCode**.
See below:

```
from functions.by_continent import scatter_plot
from flask import Flask, render_template, request 


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():

    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])

def getCountry():
    **country_code= scatter_plot.countryCode**
    if request.method == 'POST':

        scatter_img = scatter_plot(countryVal)
        return render_template('index.html', 
                               scatter_img= scatter_img,  
                               country=countryVal)
    else:
        return render_template('index.html')
```

But I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'countryCode'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your error: `scatter_plot` is a function, which does not have the attribute `countryCode`.

There are ways to access a function's attributes, like ones mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109289/how-can-a-function-access-its-own-attributes), but you are better off using classes. Following is an example.

```py
# in by_continent.py
# every different country val has a different class instance
class Plot:
    def __init__(self, country_val) -> None:
        self.country_val = country_val
        self.country_code = None  # not set yet

    # plots based on country_val
    # also extracts country_code before returning scatter_img
    def scatter_plot(self):
        ...
        self.country_code = pop[pop.country_name.str.lower() == current_country.lower()]["country_iso_2code"].values[0]
        ...

        return scatter_img
```

Usage:

```py
country_plot = Plot(country_val=<country value>)
scatter_img = country_plot.scatter_plot()
country_plot.country_code # is set after scatter_plot is run
```

PS: Global variables are not a good idea ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil)).

If you use globals (`countryCode` as you mention), then you might run into issues later, since globals are not thread safe.
You are better off using Sessions or a database.
Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49664010/using-variables-across-flask-routes) out.

Comment: I think I explained myself poorly? countryCode is generated inside the by_country function. I edited the initial post to hopefully bring some clarity.

Comment: In that case, you want the `scatter_plot` function to return two things: `countryCode` and `scatter_img`? Can you specify what inputs it needs and why you decided to have `countryCode` as global?

Comment: If I pass both, the image wont render...weird. 
I just need countryCode to be available to the app, so I thought I had to make it a global variable?

Comment: @ruthpozuelo I have updated the code. As mentioned, I think its a better idea to have Sessions or a database if you want globals. For a simpler case, feel free to use the class attribute (`country_plot.country_code` directly).

Comment: I am not good enough to do classes, but hopefully my next steps.
What worked for me was to return both the image and the variable and then get them from the results (that is where i was having issues).

Answer (score 0):

ok, this is what worked (even though it is not very sofisticated.

I returned both the image and the variable from the by_country function:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def scatter_plot(countryVal):
    
   global countryCode

   ......

   pop = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * from population", conn)

   df = df.filter(['Edition','Country/Territory','Region', 'Total', 'status_name'])

   countryCode = pop[pop.country_name.str.lower() == current_country.lower()]['country_iso_2code'].values[0]

    .....

    return (scatter_img, countryCode)
```

and then I got the correct values in the app like this:

```
from functions.by_continent import scatter_plot
from flask import Flask, render_template, request 


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():

    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])

def getCountry():

    if request.method == 'POST':

        scatter_results = scatter_plot(countryVal)
        return render_template('index.html', 
                               scatter_img= scatter_results[0],
                               country_code= scatter_results[1],  
                               country=countryVal)
    else:
        return render_template('index.html')
```

Hopefully it helps others!